# Scaling, mirroring, how does it really work?

Tags: objects, operator

I don't really understand this behavior :

All is done in object mode.
Here are 6 identical shapes, from top to bottom rotated around the Y axis, respectively 0, -45, -90, -135, -180 and -225°.

Now I scale them -1 with 3D cursor as pivot and along the X axis (shapes on the right are 'witness') :

[image]

Now, the scaled shapes, from top to bottom (all kept their original rotation around Y) :

- 1 : scale X = -1, effectively mirrored (like from a mirror)
- 2 : scale X = -1, but not mirrored ?
- 3 : scale *Z* = -1, and appears mirrored
- 4 : scales X and Z = -1, not mirrored ?
- 5 : scale X = -1, mirrored
- 6 : scale X = -1, not mirrored ?

Why all that ?

Note : I don't want to obtain any particular result here (I know how to correct things if needed), but I just want to understand why it works like that.

[image]

Comment: FYI, related to this https://developer.blender.org/T42834. Indicated as "this can be closed as a known limit." by Campbell Barton

Answer (score 2):

This matter because you don't apply rotation to original objects.
"CTRL+A - rotation" should solve this.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the point, for me : the question is "why" (as I told in the note at the end of the question, I know how to obtain what I want in that matter). But I am questioning here to understand why these results are so counter intuitive.