# Light issue when joining two objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, light

I'm fairly new to Blender (and modeling in general), and I have an issue that occurs when trying to join two objects! I'm trying to attach a weapon to the hand of a human, but when I do so, the lighting for either object messes up completely!
I've done this before with similar models without this issue ever happening, so I can't figure out why it does so in this case! I would really appreciate it if I could get some help on this matter! :)

[image]

Comment: Do you have some modifiers or some scales on these meshes ?

Comment: I would check that your modifier stacks (if you have them) are applied and that your transforms/scales/rotations are applied with ctrl + a before joining.

Comment: Thank you guys! :) It appears that somehow it is my scale that is messing up the lighting of the materials when it is applied! Now the question is, how do I circumvent this? Keep in mind, you may have to talk to me as if I'm a baby, because I'm still very new to all of this, and I have no idea how I have added any sort of scale component (when I haven't done this on the other, very similar, models). :'D So how do I get rid of it?

EDIT: Actually, I think I did a mirror transform when I was making the gun. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Lemon and Aoradon, you solved my problem! It appears it was the mirror transform I had used that somehow caused this problem to occur! Flipping it back and applying all modifiers/scales/etc. before copying it in and joining it with the other mesh, completely solved my issue!

Thank you guys very much :)

Comment: FYI, I have posted this question (with no real answer), but I commented the question as I discovered there were tricky things under it http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57961/scaling-mirroring-how-does-it-really-work. You cannot prevent these kind of things, but there are always symptoms of it... so, with practice, this is rarely a real problem, at the end...